# how to determine the constructor which called with empty braced initializer?

Tags: c++, initialization, c++14, default-constructor

I tested the following code on two different compilers, I could not determine how the object w2 is constructed.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Widget
{
public:
    Widget()
    {
        std::cout <<count++<<" "<< __FUNCTION__ << "()"<< std::endl;

    }
    Widget(std::initializer_list<int> il)
    {
        std::cout <<count++<< " " <<__FUNCTION__ << "(std::initializer_list<int> il)" << std::endl;
    }
private:
    static int count;
};
int Widget::count = 0;
int main()
{

    Widget w1();
    Widget w2{};
    Widget w3{ 10, 5 };
    Widget w4({});
}
```

the output on the two compilers was:

```
0 Widget()
1 Widget(std::initializer_list<int> il)
2 Widget(std::initializer_list<int> il)
```

Comment: `Widget w1();` does not create an object. It's a function declaration for `w1` with return type `Widget`

Comment: https://herbsutter.com/2013/05/09/gotw-1-solution/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I could not determine how the object `w2` is constructed.

`w2` is constructed by the default constructor; as you can see from the output

> `0 Widget()`

Firstly, `Widget` is not an [aggregate type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization), it has user-defined constructors; then `Widget w2{};` performs [value initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization).

> In all cases, if the empty pair of braces {} is used and T is an
>   aggregate type, aggregate-initialization is performed instead of
>   value-initialization.
>
> If T is a class type that has no default constructor but has a
>   constructor taking std::initializer_list, list-initialization is
>   performed.

Both above cases are false here. Then

> 1) if T is a class type with no default constructor or with a user-provided or deleted default constructor, the object is default-initialized;

then in [default initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization),

(emphasis mine)

> if T is a `non-POD (until C++11)` class type, the constructors are considered and subjected to overload resolution against the empty argument list. The constructor selected (**which is one of the default constructors**) is called to provide the initial value for the new object;

---

BTW: `Widget w1();` is not a variable definition, but a function declaration; which declares a function named `w1` taking nothing and returning `Widget`. That's why you only get 3 outputs. You might want `Widget w1;`.

Comment: @songyuanyao -- this is **not** the [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). The most vexing parse is far more subtle.